# How to use angular virtual scroll with two dimensions?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I'like to use angular virtual scroll on a pivot table that has potentially many rows and many columns, so i'd like to have virtual scrolling both horizontaly and verticaly.

Is there a way to do that with angular material sdk or should i write it myself ?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with Angular cdk

Comment: There is some good discussion on Virtual Scroll requirement implementation. Might be helpful for for you.
[angular/components/issues/10122](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10122)

Comment: Why not use `mat-table`?  It has implicit virtual loading in one direction?

Comment: @nathaniel And add virtual scroll in the horizontal direction ?

Comment: I think you may need to write one yourself.  All the options I looked at give you horizontal or vertical but not both.

Comment: Have you found solution for it ?. I'm also solving same problem.